# iPhone broken screen access with VNC (or anything)

Tags: iphone, jailbreak, ssh, remote-desktop

My iPhone 5 (iOS 6, jailbroken) battery inflated a little bit couple of weeks ago, but enough for the screen to pop out. Screen and touch were still fine, until last week-end where stripes start to appear. I had to wriggle a bit the screen (or the screen connector) to make them disappear but now it's completely off (there's only backlighting).

I try to access the screen to display some (jailbreak) information iTunes does not want to restore.
**I try to have the iPhone screen displayed on my laptop, with the ability to control it.**

I have root SSH access and Veency installed (but disabled). I tried to enable it with SSH but did not find how to.

Is there a Mac software that only requires plugin to display screen (and control it), or a way in SSH (or other) to enable Veency so I can try to connect via VNC?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use Quicktime on your Mac:

1. Connect your iPhone to your Mac.
2. Open Quicktime.
3. Select File > New Movie Recording.
4. Next to the record button, there is a downward pointing arrow, click on it and select your iPhone.
5. Your iPhone screen should show up.

This won't let you control your iPhone but at least you can see the screen.

Comment: Already try that but nothing appears to be my iPhone in QT (iOS 7+ only maybe?) – and I do want control it :)

Comment: @Joan yes, it is iOS 7 or later only.